# JDBC read with partitioning - first/last partition skewed

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, partitioning

I am reading dataframe from JDBC source using partitioning as described [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html), using `numPartitions`, `partitionColumn`, `upperBound`, `lowerBound`. I've been using this quite often, but this time I noticed something weird. With `numPartition = 32` and 124 distinct partition column values, this split data into 30 smaller chunks and 2 large.

```
Task 1  - partitions   1 ..  17 (17 values!)
Task 2  - partitions  18 ..  20 (3 values)
Task 3  - partitions  21 ..  23 (3 values)
Task 4  - partitions  24 ..  26 (3 values)
...
Task 30 - partitions 102 .. 104 (3 values)
Task 31 - partitions 105 .. 107 (3 values)
Task 32 - partitions 108 .. 124 (17 values!)
```

I'm just wondering whether this actually worked as expected and what I can do to make it split into even chunks apart from experimenting maybe with different values of `numPartitions` (note that I number of values can vary and I'm not always able to predict it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through source code of [JDBCRelation.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/65261721a5205e2ee0e370cc451eb6bcc2d015d1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JDBCRelation.scala#L126-L142) and found out that this is exactly how it's implemented. It first calculates stride as `(upperBound - lowerBound) / numPartitions`, which in my case is `124 / 32 = 3`, and then remaining values are allocated evenly to fist and last partition.

I was a bit unlucky with the number of values, because if I had 4 more, then `128 / 32 = 4` and it would nicely align 32 partitions of 4 values each.

I ended up pre-querying the table for exact range and then manually providing predicates using:

```scala
   val partRangeSql = "SELECT min(x), max(x) FROM table")
   val (partMin, partMax) =
     spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, s"($partRangeSql) _", props).as[(Int, Int)].head
   val predicates = (partMin to partMax).map(p => s"x = $p").toArray
   spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, s"table", predicates, props)
```

That makes it 124 partitions (one per value), so need to be careful with overloading database server (but I'm limiting number of executors so that not running more than 32 concurrent sessions).

I guess adjusting `lowerBound`/`upperBound` so that `upperBound - lowerBound` is a multiple of `numPartitions` would also do the work.